# How can I access my own Word templates in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, templates

I am using my very own Word and PowerPoint templates and store them in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Templates`.

In Word 2007 accessing them was as easy as eating a cookie. In Word 2010 this is made a bit more tricky (to promote all this Microsoft on-line content?), but own templates are still fairly easily accessible:

[image]

In Word 2013, either I am blind or I can't access them at all:

[image]

The only way I see is to locate `.dotx` or `.dotm` file in its physical location, double-click it and start editing a new document based on that template. A very inconvenient solution. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a better way?

You need to specify the location of your personal templates:

> **Personal templates in Word for Windows 2013 and 2016**
>
> In previous versions of Word the best way to start a new document from
> a template was to click File > New > My Templates. In Word 2013 and
> 2016 this command no longer exists.
>
> **In fact, there is no way to access personal templates, only the Featured templates provided by Microsoft, unless you specify the
> Default personal templates location.**
>
> To specify the Default personal templates location:
>
> - Click File > Options > Save.
> - In the Default personal templates location enter the path to your personal template folder. This path should be the same as the User
>   templates folder.
>
> Note that you cannot browse to a location; you must either correctly
> type a path or paste text for a path. To use the same folder as the
> User templates folder type:
>
> ```
> %appdata%\microsoft\templates
> ```
>
> Now, when you click File > New you can choose from Featured or
> Personal templates:
>
> [image: word 2013 file new]

Source [Personal templates in Word 2013 and 2016 - Office Templates](http://www.officetemplates.co.uk/personal-templates/)